# Initialization of std::vector<unsigned int> with a list of consecutive unsigned integers

Tags: c++, stl, initialization, std, stdvector

I want to use a special method to initialize a `std::vector<unsigned int>` which is described in a C++ book I use as a reference (the German book 'Der C++ Programmer' by Ulrich Breymann, in case that matters). In that book is a section on sequence types of the STL, referring in particular to `list`, `vector` and `deque`. In this section he writes that there are two special constructors of such sequence types, namely, if `X`refers to such a type,

```
X(n, t) // creates a sequence with n copies of t
X(i, j) // creates a sequence from the elements of the interval [i, j)
```

I want to use the second one for an interval of `unsigned int`, that is

```
std::vector<unsigned int> l(1U, 10U);
```

to get a list initialized with `{1,2,...,9}`. What I get, however, is a vector with one `unsigned int` with value 10 :-| Does the second variant exist, and if yes, how do I force that it is called?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Reread the paragraphs near there describing what each of the parameters are.  Specifically, it should mention that `i` and `j` are not values, but *iterators*.  This constructor is very commonly used to make copies of other types of containers.  If you want to get a sequence of values, the [Boost library](http://www.boost.org/) provides a [counting iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/iterator/doc/counting_iterator.html), that does exactly what you want.

```
std::vector<unsigned int> numbers(
     boost::counting_iterator<unsigned int>(0U),
     boost::counting_iterator<unsigned int>(10U));
```

Comment: thanks, works as desired! The book is a bit unspecific with respect to that particular constructor, but later on the letters i, j are in fact used explicitly for iterators. Th.

Answer (score 21):

there are at least three ways that you can do that. One was mentioned earlier by Brian

```
//method 1
generate(v.begin(), v.end(), [] { static int i {1}; return i++; });
```

You can also use std::iota if you are using c++11

```
//method 2
iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 1);
```

Or instead you can initialize your container with 1s and then do a partial sum on that. I don't think anybody will use this third method anyway :)

```
//method 3
vector<int> v(n, 1);                                                     
partial_sum(v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin());
```

Comment: Method 3 is rather handy if you want to generate an array containing the cumulative sums. Add another `partial_sum(v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin())` and for n = 5, you get {1, 3, 6, 10, 15}.

Comment: Note, `generate` here uses static. Put it within a function, call it multiple times and it will keep counting. Use `ValueType i = {1}; std::generate(first, last, [&i] { return i++; });` instead.

Answer (score 3):

A non-boost way to do this with a self-incrementing iterator.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

static int NUM_ITEMS = 10;

class gen_range {
    public:
        gen_range(int i) { idx = i; }
        int operator()() { return (idx++); };

    int idx;
};

int main() {

    std::vector<int> x(NUM_ITEMS);
    std::generate_n(x.begin(), NUM_ITEMS, gen_range(0));

    for (int i=0; i < x.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << x[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, that variant does not exist. The second constructor initializes a vector from two iterators that point into another sequence.

Here is an example of the "two-iterator" constructor in action:

```
int fill_data[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
std::vector<int> v(fill_data, fill_data + 4);
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit request, I incorrectly marked it as incorrect. :) I have fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

C++11:

```
std::vector<int> idxs (n);

std::generate_n (idxs.begin (), n, [] { static int i {1}; return i++; });
```