# How to insert a range of elements in a set in C++?

Tags: c++, stl, set

Ok , so this is a short query.

I have a Set container say a ;

c=5 , d= 42 are integers.

I want to insert all integers from 5 to 42 in the set **without** using the for loop.

How can i do this??

Finally a should look like  {5,6,7.......,42}

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert overload five.

Comment: The best way to do this is with a for loop. Why would you request some other way?

Comment: What are the reasons against a `for` loop?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley      Actually this is a part of a problem i am solving , so i need to bring down the complexity of my code , hence i thought there may be an efficient method to create intervals using set

Comment: Your going to have a loop.  Whether you abstract that away with a function or not is your call but you need to do N operations and to do that you use a loop.

Comment: @NathanOliver Ohh , guess i have to rethink the Algo then , thanks btw :-)

Comment: @AyushGoyal I think you need a vectorization/parallelization library to  bring down the complexity of your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to efficiently insert a range of consecutive integers into a std::set?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18295333/how-to-efficiently-insert-a-range-of-consecutive-integers-into-a-stdset)

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <set>

template<class OutputIterator, class T>
OutputIterator iota_rng(OutputIterator first, T low, T high)
{
        return std::generate_n(first, high - low, [&, value = low]() mutable { return value++; });
} 

int main()
{
    std::set<int> s;
    iota_rng(std::inserter(s, s.begin()), 5, 43);
    for (auto elem : s) {
        std::cout << elem << ", ";    
    }
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b756f04227dad684)

In the [**range-v3 library**](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) (proposed as a technical specification) you can write it even more concisely as:

```
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

int main()
{
    std::set<int> s = ranges::view::iota(5, 43);
    for (auto elem : s) {
        std::cout << elem << ", ";    
    }
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/55ae45f6434c1392)