# C++ Vector Range Constructor

Tags: c++, vector

I was looking over some C++ documentation when it occurred to me that the vector container doesn't have a constructor that 'easily' allows the user to pass a range of values - a min and a max - and have a vector constructed which has elements from min -> max. I thought this was odd so I tried writing my own and discovered it was non-trivial. Here's my solution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename T>
class MyIterator: public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, int>
{

public:

  MyIterator(T val):value(val) {}
  MyIterator(const MyIterator & m):value(m.value) {}

  MyIterator& operator ++() 
  {
  ++value; 
    return *this; 
  }

  MyIterator operator ++(int) 
  { 
    MyIterator temp(*this); 
    operator ++();
    return temp; 
  }

  bool operator ==(const MyIterator & m) const { return value == m.value; }
  bool operator !=(const MyIterator & m) const { return !(value == m.value); }
  T& operator *() { return value; }

private:

  T value;

};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{ 
  std::vector<int> my_vec(MyIterator<int>(100), MyIterator<int>(400));

  std::copy(my_vec.begin(), my_vec.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));

  return 0;
}
```

Does the new C++ have a solution for this?

Comment: I think not... in C++11 there's just a new option to fill a vector while creating it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Initialization of std::vector<unsigned int> with a list of consecutive unsigned integers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855189/initialization-of-stdvectorunsigned-int-with-a-list-of-consecutive-unsigned)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++11 there is the [`std::iota`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) function. Otherwise you have e.g. [`std::fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) and [`std::fill_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill_n), or [`std::generate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate) and [`std::generate_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate_n).

Comment: Nice solution but I was thinking about creating the sequence of numbers in the vector constructor like I did in my solution.

Answer (score 1):

For C++11 there was no substantial work on changing the algorithms or containers to make them easier usable (there are a couple of new algorithms and the containers were made aware of allocators and rvalues). Neither is there a substantial change for C++14.

There is some hope for C++17, though: the Ranges Study Group is looking at concepts to make the algorithms and containers easier to use. That said, it isn't clear where that journey will travel to.